# Is there any way to configure @fastify/caching per route?

Tags: javascript, fastify

We came across a question regarding `fastify-caching`. Is there a config setting to set `max-age` per route or disable cache completely for one specific route?

We did find that setting expiresIn will affect the caching globally. Please refer:

```js
{
  privacy: 'value',
  expiresIn: 300,
  cache: {get, set},
  cacheSegment: 'segment-name'
}
```

Source: https://github.com/fastify/fastify-caching

The only way to disable cache was to use HTTP cache headers.

Answer (score 1):

No, today there is not such a feature - but it would be a good addition.
It has been done already on plugins like [@fastify/rate-limit](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-rate-limit#options-on-the-endpoint-itself)

Anyway, I must say that you could do that in any case, thanks to encapsulation:

```js
const http = require('http')
const app = require('fastify')()
const fastifyCaching = require('@fastify/caching')

app.register(function plugin (app, opts, next) {
  app.register(
    fastifyCaching,
    {
      privacy: fastifyCaching.privacy.PUBLIC,
      expiresIn: 1000
    },
  )

  app.get('/one', (req, reply) => {
    reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
  })

  next()
})
app.register(function plugin (app, opts, next) {
  app.register(
    fastifyCaching,
    { privacy: fastifyCaching.privacy.PUBLIC, expiresIn: 5000 },
  )

  app.get('/two', (req, reply) => {
    reply.send({ hello: 'world' })
  })

  next()
})

app.listen({ port: 3000 }, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err

  http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/one', (res) => {
    console.log({ one: res.headers })
  })
  http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/two', (res) => {
    console.log({ two: res.headers })
  })
})
```

Output:

```
{
  one: {
    'cache-control': 'public, max-age=1000',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'content-length': '17',
    date: 'Thu, 06 Apr 2023 06:13:52 GMT',
    connection: 'close'
  }
}
{
  two: {
    'cache-control': 'public, max-age=5000',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'content-length': '17',
    date: 'Thu, 06 Apr 2023 06:13:52 GMT',
    connection: 'close'
  }
}
```

Further reading about encapsulation:

- https://backend.cafe/the-complete-guide-to-the-fastify-plugin-system
- video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnnL7fAKqNU